# How to connect AWS SQS to Thingsboard?

Tags: amazon-sqs, thingsboard

I'm trying to connect a AWS SQS message queue to Thingsboard (cloud) and due to my ignorance struggling to see where the data is going.

I have an external application that is sending data messages via an AWS SWS queue, but can't figure out how to setup Thingsboard to connect to these messages.

I have configured an integration with the SQS queue url and access keys.  But I don't see any telemetry coming in.

I have a basic rule chain to save messages, but the debug for this also shows no data.

I'm out of my depth really on understanding the relationship of the SWS integration that is setup and the Rule Chain.  I'm guessing it is the SQS config in Thingboard that is not correct, but don't know what it is that may be wrong.

Are there any tutorials that explain this?  A bit of advice on what needs setup/testing will be of great help.

For reference I'm able to see data posted to a Thingsboard device when using curl or postman.  This data shows in the Rule chain debug.

Comment: I'm a ThingsBoard user and use AWS SQS with my TB instance. What type of installation is your TB? Did you install it on a stand-alone server, on AWS EC2, Docker, etc.

Comment: It's the TB cloud subscription, so no issue with installation or running environment.